# Get Lat and long from postcode without using the map android

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, postal-code

I have an app that calculate the distances between my current location to the specific location. I am able to do this by entering the lat and long manually. is the a way to get lat and long from the postcode provided by the user without using the map because I don't need to see the map in this instance:

The postcode is collected from an Input Text box from the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Geocoder` `getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults)`to transform address information to Latitude, Longitude. Documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can user any free service available for reverse Geo Coding:

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/06/21/7-free-geocoding-apis-google-bing-yahoo-and-mapquest/